# This field name is not known - Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, crystal-reports-2010

I'm using VS2013 - CR12

I create 2 total summary fields in my report and all is working well Preview And Publish.

When I create a formula with subtraction between these summary fields, it is working well in preview, but when I publish the report I see this error:

> This field name is not known. Details: errorKind Error in File
>   temp_e612bcb8-bec6-4cb3-8578-3ccbb283dddc
>   2260_8300_{1DA56A4D-D201-4574-89F9-B39CAACCF547}.rpt: Error in formula
>   Dif: ' ' This field name is not known. Details: errorKind

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please update your answer with code so that we have a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: This Problem Show When Have Null Data So Must Be Make Sure Data Come Without Null